# 複数パーティクルを組み合わせたエフェクトについて

Tags: unity2d

初めて質問させて頂きます。
Unity初心者です。

Unity製のスマホアプリに使用するエフェクトを、パーティクルを複数組み合わせてプロジェクトの画面に合わせて作りました。
アプリは複数人で制作しており、私はエフェクトをパッケージファイルにしてプロジェクトを作った方にお送りしました。

すると「エフェクトの位置や大きさがプロジェクトの画面と合っていない」と言われ、プレハブモードでエフェクトを確認した所組み合わせたパーティクルの位置が大きくズレてしまっておりました。
きちんとプロジェクト画面に合わせて作ったつもりだったのですが、プレハブ化した際にズレてしまったようです。

こちらを検索しても他のサイトを調べても解決方法が見つからず困っています。
拙い文章で恐縮ですが、どうすれば良いかご教授お願いいたします。